# Find highest numbered files in directory

Tags: command-line, bash, regex, sed

Scenario:
A backup system creates rar archives and splits them in 100 MB parts.
I would like to find the highest numbered files within this directory.

For example in- and output:

**Input:**

```
Backup_UniqueName123_part1.rar
Backup_UniqueName123_part2.rar
Backup_UniqueName123_part3.rar
Backup_RandomName_part1.rar
Backup_RandomName_part2.rar
Backup_Server_part1.rar
Backup_Server_part2.rar
```

**Output:**

```
Backup_UniqueName123_part3.rar
Backup_RandomName_part2.rar
Backup_Server_part2.rar
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DIRPATH="/where/youre/files/are"

BASE=''
NUM=0
while read F; do
  test -e "$F" || continue
  FB=$(echo "$F" | sed 's/_part[0-9]*\.rar$//')
  FN=$(echo "$F" | sed 's/.rar$// ; s/.*\([0-9][0-9]*\)$/\1/')
  if test "$BASE" == "$FB" ; then
    test $FN -gt $NUM && NUM=$FN
  else
    test -n "$BASE" && echo "${BASE}_part$NUM.rar"
    BASE=$FB
    NUM=$FN
  fi
done < <(ls -1 "$DIRPATH")
```

Explanation:

- We extract base name and number from each filename
- We keep only the highest number
- When a new base name is encountered, we print the old base name and old highest number

Answer (score 0):

You could also you `awk` to process the file names:

```
{
    match($0, /(^.+)_part([0-9]+)\.rar/, parts);
    key = parts[1];
    new_count = parts[2];
    old_count = data[key];
    if (new_count > old_count) {
        data[key] = new_count;
    }
}

END {
    for (key in data) {
        print key, data[key];
    }
}
```